# How Windows Task Manager generate the memory usage percentage for each process

Tags: windows

In Windows Task Manager, the memory usage of each process is the value of "private working set" when display as "Values". But when display as "Percent", the percentage is not calculated with the "private working set". The denominator to get the percentage is also not the total available physical memory but more like to be the "In use" memory. This is also total different with the device memory percentage calculation which is generated by the available physical memory and total physical memory. Does anyone know the how Windows Task Manager generates the memory usage percentage for each process? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JdMX.png)